Calling a smart contract without the ABI in Web3.py
I need to call a function of an implementation contract. The problem is I'm not the creator of the contract and it's source code hasn't been verified on ethersan, hence I don't have the ABI.
I extracted calldata(0x12345...) from tx to the proxy contract. I know metodId and 3 args(address, uint256, address) and I modified args to my needs.
Is it possible to send a transaction calling a fallback function of the proxy without implementation ABI, just with raw calldata?

You can simply create a transaction in the web3

address: Contract address

Then add to the data  field

First 4 bytes (32 bits): function selector
Following 3 * 32 bytes (256 bits): function arguments (address, uint256, address), zero-padded, so-called ABI encode

